# Flutter Hero multiple elements reverse animation starts in center

Tags: flutter, hero

I am trying to create a hero animation with multiple elements, so far my code is as follows:

main.dart:

```
import 'package:animations/animations.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_playground/screen_two.dart';
import 'package:flutter_playground/transition/hero_dialog_route.dart';
import 'package:flutter_playground/transition/hero_page_route.dart';
import 'package:flutter_playground/transition_open_container_wrapper.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 1,
            crossAxisSpacing: 4,
            mainAxisSpacing: 4,
          ),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: 100,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return getChild(index);
          }),
    );
  }

  Widget getChild(int index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          HeroDialogRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenTwo(index: index)),
        );
      },
      child: getCard(index),
    );
  }

  Widget getCard2(int index) {
    return OpenContainerWrapper(
      isRootNavigator: true,
      closedBuilder: (context, voidCallback) {
        return InkWell(
          onTap: voidCallback,
          child: getCard(index),
        );
      },
      openBuilder: (context, voidCallback) {
        return Container(height: 300, width: 300, child: ScreenTwo(index: index),);
      },
      transitionType: ContainerTransitionType.fade,
      onClosed: (value) {},
    );
  }

  Widget getCard(int index) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Hero(
          createRectTween: (Rect? begin, Rect? end) {
            return CurvedRectArcTween(begin: begin, end: end);
          },
          tag: 'hero_card_${index}',
          child: Card(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: double.infinity,
              width: double.infinity,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Hero(
          tag: 'hero_image_${index}',
          createRectTween: (Rect? begin, Rect? end) {
            return CurvedRectArcTween(begin: begin, end: end);
          },
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/200', fit: BoxFit.contain,),
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

screen_two:

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Created by ali on 12/19/22.
class ScreenTwo extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;

  const ScreenTwo({super.key, required this.index});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ScreenTwoState();
  }
}

class _ScreenTwoState extends State<ScreenTwo> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 0, sigmaY: 0), child: Center(
            child: getContent(),
          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getContent() {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Hero(
          tag: 'hero_card_${widget.index}',
          createRectTween: (Rect? begin, Rect? end) {
            return RectTween(begin: begin, end: end);
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 416,
            height: 416,
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Hero(
            tag: 'hero_image_${widget.index}',
            createRectTween: (Rect? begin, Rect? end) {
              return RectTween(begin: begin, end: end);
            },
            child: Card(
              child: ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://picsum.photos/200',
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 200,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

hero_page_route:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Created by ali on 12/24/22.
class CurvedRectArcTween extends RectTween {

  late double a;
  late double b;
  late double c;
  late double d;

  CurvedRectArcTween({
    Rect? begin,
    Rect? end,
    double? a,
    double? b,
    double? c,
    double? d,
  }) : super(begin: begin, end: end) {
    this.a = a ?? 0;
    this.b = b ?? 0;
    this.c = c ?? 0;
    this.d = d ?? 0;
  }

  @override
  Rect? lerp(double t) {
    Cubic easeInOut = Cubic(a, b , c, d);
    double curvedT = easeInOut.transform(t);
    return super.lerp(curvedT);
  }
}
```

and hero_dialog_route.dart:

```
import 'package:animations/animations.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Created by ali on 11/22/22.
class HeroDialogRoute<T> extends PageRoute<T> {
  final WidgetBuilder builder;

  HeroDialogRoute({required this.builder}) : super();

  @override
  bool get opaque => false;

  @override
  bool get barrierDismissible => true;

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => const Duration(milliseconds: 1000);

  @override
  bool get maintainState => true;

  @override
  Color get barrierColor => Colors.black54;

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
    return FadeScaleTransition(
      animation: animation,
      child: child,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
    return builder(context);
  }

  @override
  String? get barrierLabel => null;
}
```

transition_open_container_wrapper.dart:

```
class OpenContainerWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const OpenContainerWrapper({
    Key? key,
    required this.isRootNavigator,
    required this.closedBuilder,
    required this.openBuilder,
    required this.transitionType,
    required this.onClosed,
  }) :super(key: key);

  final CloseContainerBuilder closedBuilder;
  final OpenContainerBuilder<bool?> openBuilder;
  final ContainerTransitionType transitionType;
  final ClosedCallback<bool?> onClosed;
  final bool isRootNavigator;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OpenContainer<bool>(
      useRootNavigator: isRootNavigator,
      closedElevation: 0,
      openColor: Colors.transparent,
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 450),
      closedShape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(),
      openShape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(),
      transitionType: transitionType,
      openBuilder: openBuilder,
      onClosed: onClosed,
      tappable: false,
      closedBuilder: closedBuilder,
    );
  }
}
```

Here is gif to visualize what the code does:
https://i.imgur.com/xRcRWzH.mp4[image]

As you can see, when hero starts with both background card and image and scales up nicely until the animation finishes. But when returning back, the image suddenly jumps into the center and returning animation doesn't look as good as beginning animation. How to make those two run together when returning back to first positions in the grid like it does in first animation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please include the transition_open_container_wrapper.dart file?

Comment: Yes, added now.

Comment: hey @AliYucelAkgul I added my answer :), I hope it helps

Answer (score 8):

I simplified your example fixing some parts of the layout and also I'm not using the `animation` package to make that transition effect.

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 1,
          crossAxisSpacing: 4,
          mainAxisSpacing: 4,
        ),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: 100,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return getChild(index);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getChild(int index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          PageRouteBuilder(
            opaque: false,
            barrierColor: Colors.black38,
            transitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
            reverseTransitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
            transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, _, child) =>
                FadeTransition(
              opacity: animation,
              child: child,
            ),
            pageBuilder: (context, _, __) => ScreenTwo(index: index),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: getCard(index),
    );
  }

  Widget getCard(int index) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned.fill(
          child: Hero(
            createRectTween: (Rect? begin, Rect? end) {
              return CurvedRectArcTween(begin: begin, end: end);
            },
            tag: 'hero_card_$index',
            child: const Card(),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned.fill(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: Hero(
              tag: 'hero_image_$index',
              createRectTween: (Rect? begin, Rect? end) {
                return CurvedRectArcTween(begin: begin, end: end);
              },
              child: Image.network(
                'https://picsum.photos/200',
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ScreenTwo extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;

  const ScreenTwo({super.key, required this.index});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ScreenTwoState();
  }
}

class _ScreenTwoState extends State<ScreenTwo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 500,
              width: 416,
              child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 0, sigmaY: 0),
                child: getContent(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getContent() {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned.fill(
          child: Hero(
            tag: 'hero_card_${widget.index}',
            createRectTween: (Rect? begin, Rect? end) {
              return RectTween(begin: begin, end: end);
            },
            child: const Card(),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned.fill(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: Hero(
              tag: 'hero_image_${widget.index}',
              createRectTween: (Rect? begin, Rect? end) {
                return RectTween(begin: begin, end: end);
              },
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://picsum.photos/200',
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Result

[image]